# Effect of assigning JavaScript function to variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

In JavaScript, I can define a function and assign it to a variable:

`var myVar = function myFunc(){};`

or define the function standalone:

`function myFunc(){};`

What are the use cases for the first approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

functions declared to variables are not hoisted to the top of the scope

```
function run() {

   fn1(); // logs "hi"
   fn2(); // error

   function fn1 () { console.log("hi"); }
   var fn2 = function () { console.log("hi again"); };    

}
```

See this previous related answer. [Are named functions or anonymous functions preferred in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript/10081753#10081753)

This will end up looking similar to this after the parse runs through it

```
function run() {

       function fn1 () { console.log("hi"); }
       var fn2;

       fn1(); // logs "hi"
       fn2(); // error


       fn2 = function () { console.log("hi again"); };    

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Trevor. Is there a reason/logic behind this difference?

Comment: It's just how the JS parser was written. Perhaps this article will be of assistance. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/. I used to have this great article on how it actually stored the vars, but I am unable to find it. :(