# What is the difference between these two?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I saw the following JavaScript functions works exactly same, Then what is the difference between them **other than syntax**.
The function are:

```
var functionName=function(){
    //some code here
}; 

function functionName(){
    //some code here
}
```

I call them in the same way as:

```
functionName();
```

Please dont' tell me there syntax is different, Other than that is there any difference like

```
1)speed of execution
2)Memory utilization etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: function expression vs function declaration

Comment: Exaact Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times in StackOverflow. It is just the way of naming. So taking up some points from the answers, I would say:

1. Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved ("hoisted") invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter. Function parameters and language-defined names are, obviously, already there.
2. Advantages & Disadvantages:

   There are few advantages to naming functions:

   - names for meta analysis. `functionInstance.name` will show you the name.
   - Far more importantly, the name will be printed in stack traces.
   - names also help write self documenting or literate code.

   There is a single disadvantage to named functions expressions

   - IE has memory leaks for NFE
3. **Another main difference**

   The difference is that `functionTwo` is defined at parse-time for a script block, whereas `functionOne` is defined at run-time.  For example:

   ```
   <script>
     // Error
     functionOne();

     var functionOne = function() {
     }
   </script>

   <script>
     // No error
     functionTwo();

     function functionTwo() {
     }
   </script>
   ```

**References**

1. [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
2. [Are named functions or anonymous functions preferred in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript)
3. [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)
4. [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).
5. [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Thank you this cleared my doubt!

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st one is Named Function Expressions, which should return some value to the caller.
2. 2nd one is just a function, it's upto you whether you return value or not

Comment: I have used 1)function without returing any value