# Why is a function declaration within a condition block hoisted to function scope in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Why the following codes output different results between Chrome and Firefox?

```
f = function() {return true;}; 
g = function() {return false;}; 
(function() { 
   if (g() && [] == ![]) { 
      f = function f() {return false;}; 
      function g() {return true;} 
   } 
})(); 
console.log(f());
```

In Chrome: the result is `false`. However, in Firefox, it is `true`.

The key line of the above codes is line 4, and base on my knowledge of function name hoisting, the function `g` should be in line 6, namely the line 2 is overridden by line 6. IMO, the behavior of Chrome is correct.

Am I right on this? if so, why Firefox outputs different results?

Comment: Because Chrome hoists `g` and Firefox doesn't. Don't use function declarations inside blocks. Firefox is actually more correct in this case, but there is still some implementation dependent magic going on. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression

Comment: This should be an answer, rather than a comment. (Although I would argue that neither is more or less correct, as the result isn't defined by the spec.)

Comment: @IanClelland: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate, but I'm not feeling searching for it on a phone.

Comment: `if (g() && [] == ![]) { ` could be changed to just `if (g()) { ` and the example would still work, and be a bit clearer IMHO

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ECMAScript 5, the current official specification of the JavaScript language, does not define the behavior for function declarations inside blocks.

Quoting [Kangax](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks):

> *FunctionDeclarations* are only allowed to appear in *Program* or *FunctionBody*. Syntactically, they **can not appear in *Block*** (`{ ... }`) — such as that of `if`, `while` or `for` statements. This is because *Blocks* can only contain *Statements*, not *SourceElements*, which *FunctionDeclaration* is. If we look at production rules carefully, we can see that the only way *Expression* is allowed directly within *Block* is when it is part of *ExpressionStatement*. However, *ExpressionStatement* is explicitly defined **to not begin with "function" keyword**, and this is exactly why *FunctionDeclaration* cannot appear directly within a *Statement* or *Block* (note that *Block* is merely a list of *Statements*).
>
> Because of these restrictions, whenever function appears directly in a block (such as in the previous example) it should actually be **considered a syntax error**, not function declaration or expression. The problem is that almost none of the implementations I've seen parse these functions strictly per rules (exceptions are BESEN and DMDScript). They interpret them in proprietary ways instead.

Also worth quoting the [ECMAScript 6 draft - B.3.3 Block-Level Function Declarations Web Legacy Compatibility Semantics](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics):

> Prior to the Sixth Edition, the ECMAScript specification did not define the occurrence of a *FunctionDeclaration* as an element of a Block statement’s *StatementList*. However, support for that form of *FunctionDeclaration* was an allowable extension and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations permitted them. Unfortunately, the semantics of such declarations differ among those implementations. [...]

---

As ES5 does not define the behavior for function declarations inside blocks while allowing proprietary extensions, there are technically no "rights" or "wrongs". Consider them "unspecified behavior" which is not portable across different ES5-compliant environments.

Those are easy to rewrite into portable code anyway:

- Should the function declaration be hoisted to the top of the current function/global scope? Make sure the function declaration is not directly inside of a block.
- Should the function be declared only when the block executes? Assign a function expression to a variable (`var f = function() {};`). Note that there is no hoisting and the variable is still accessible outside of the block (`var` declarations are function-level scoped).

---

As per ECMAScript 6, function declarations are block-scoped, so Firefox implements the correct behavior ES6-wise.

Comment: In the last sentence of your answer, you say that function declarations are block-scoped, do you mean that they're hoisted in their block? because MDN says the opposite: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting

Comment: @pooria Even though MDN says so, functions doesn't get hoisted to the top of the program if they are inside a block.

Comment: @pooria Also MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#conditionally_created_functions  in this example, function in if block is not available in global scope.