# Scoping and closure oddities in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, closures, hoisting

This was presented yesterday at TC39. You can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/bakkot/60121065ef615c26f8bdf42839e310df):

```
var p = () => console.log(f);
{
  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f); // function f(){}

  f = 1;

  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f); // 1

  function f(){}

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f); // 1

  f = 2;

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f); // 2
}
```

Could someone please explain to me how this thing works? For the record it's **only working in non-strict mode**.

Thank you.

Comment: Specifically in relation to the hosting? This answer explains it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111087/why-is-a-function-declaration-within-a-condition-block-hoisted-to-function-scope

Comment: @CodingIntrigue: No, that doesn't cover what's happening above, which is an artifact of ES2015's Annex B and TC39 trying their best to steer through seriously treacherous waters of existing code and historically-inconsistent implementations. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Care to explain in more detail? `function f(){}` would normally be hoisted inside a normal function block and the first `undefined` should have printed the function f declaration but what about now that's defined inside a block?

Comment: @kstratis: I'm trying to, but I want to be very careful not to give you incorrect information. FYI, the relevant bit is [B.3.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-web-compat-functiondeclarationinstantiation), in particular the jiggery-pokery in step 1.a.ii.3. But I haven't been through that section in detail yet (and have to step out, sadly) so I don't have a *ready* explanation to hand. *Fascinating* situation.

Comment: I'm not sure but this is probably related to the different scope of arrow functions in es6 have compared to "normal" js behaviour.

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur: No, definitely not that. You'd get exactly the same output if the first line were `var p = function() { console.log(f); };`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the link, seems like the issue is more complicated than I realised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not claim to understand all the subtleties, but the key thing about this the almost bizarre contortions of Annex B's [§B.3.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-web-compat-functiondeclarationinstantiation).

That code is effectively this, where `f1` is a second copy of `f` specific to the lexical environment of the block (hence `let` below):

```
var p = () => console.log(f);
{
  let f1 = function f(){};;           // Note hoisting
  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f1); // function f(){}

  f1 = 1;

  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f1); // 1

  var f = f1;                          // !!!

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f1); // 1

  f1 = 2;

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f1); // 2
}
```

And of course, thanks to `var` hoisting, both `p` and `f` are effectively declared at the top of the code snippet with the initial value `undefined`:

```
var f = undefined;
var p = undefined;
p = () => console.log(f);
{
  let f1 = function f(){};;           // Note hoisting
  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f1); // function f(){}

  f1 = 1;

  p(); // undefined
  console.log(f1); // 1

  f = f1;                              // !!!

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f1); // 1

  f1 = 2;

  p(); // 1
  console.log(f1); // 2
}
```

The key bit from B.3.3.1 is that it transfers the value of the inner `f` (which I've called `f1` above) to the outer one (in the below, *F* is the string `"f"`, the name of the function being declared):

> 3. When the FunctionDeclaration *f* is evaluated, perform the following steps in place of the FunctionDeclaration Evaluation algorithm provided in 14.1.21:
>
> a. Let *fenv* be the running execution context's VariableEnvironment.
>
> b. Let *fenvRec* be *fenv*'s EnvironmentRecord.
>
> c. Let *benv* be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
>
> d. Let *benvRec* be benv's EnvironmentRecord.
>
> e. Let *fobj* be ! benvRec.GetBindingValue(*F*, false).
>
> f. Perform ! fenvRec.SetMutableBinding(*F*, *fobj*, false).
>
> g. Return NormalCompletion(empty).

Recall that the *variable* environment is function-wide, but the *lexical* environment is more constrained (to the block).

When it comes to trying to normalize function declarations in places where they were {invalid | unspecified} *(choose your term)*, TC39 have a **very** treacherous path to navigate, trying to standardize behavior while not breaking existing code that may have relied on implemenation-specific behaviors from the past (which were mutually-exclusive, but TC39 is trying to strike a balance).

Comment: Could you possible elaborate a bit more on the first two `p()`? Why do they come out as `undefined`? That bit troubles me the most; We already have hoisting and thus `f` should be already defined at that point...

Comment: @kstratis remember that hoisting doesn't _set_ a variable. All it does is change the declaration, so if you have, say `var x = 5` on line 10, _in effect_ the code is `var x;` at the top of the file, and then `x = 5` on line 10. Lines 1-9 would still have `x` equal `undefined` since the value won't be set yet. So doing `console.log(x)` on line 4 would produce `undefined`. However, if you _didn't_ have `var x` at all, it would produce ReferenceError

Comment: @kstratis: See vlaz's comment above. I've also added a second code snippet to make that explicit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this. One last piece of this puzzle is still frying my brain though: Half way through the snippet we get this: `function f(){}; p() //1`. How is this possible and how do you translate this to `f=f1; p() //1`? Thanks.

Comment: @kstratis: That's the bit I quote from the spec at the end, where it's transferring the value of the inner `f` (which I've called `f1`) to the outer `f`. It's truly bizarre, but again, they're trying to steer the best course to avoid making too much code in the wild break.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right. Could you please quote for me the exact bit (down to the line) from the spec which dictates `f=f1;` I simply can't read the spec. Too many unknowns.

Comment: @kstratis: The quoted bit *is* that bit, they just really draw it out. :-) (a) and (b) are basically saying "get the overall function's variable environment" and (c) and (d) are saying "get the block's lexical environment", then (e) reads the value of the inner `f` (`f1`) from the block's environment, and (f) writes that value to the outer `f` in the variable environment. (And yes, the spec is clear as mud.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I think I now get it. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @kstratis: No worries -- it was a fascinating one! And the spec is amazingly, amazingly hard to read... :-)