# In javascript, what are the "statement positions"?

Tags: javascript

I read [in this article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/01/06/function-definitions-in-javascript) that function declarations can appear only in statement position. I'm wondering what are these "statement positions".

Comment: Is there more context to what you read?

Comment: Places where it is valid to put statements. E.g. `if (<expression>) <statement>`. The body of a an `if` statement needs to be a statement, whereas the condition needs to be an expression. However, that's actually not quite correct. Function declarations are not statements and, officially, are not valid in all statement positions. However, most environments allow it, but apply different evaluation rules. tl;dr: it's complicated.

Comment: @David it's a blog article, I don't know if I can share the link here

Comment: You can quote the sentence above

Comment: @marco stackoverflow most definintely lets you add URLs in your post, so just hit the edit button, and say "I read on http://.... that function [...]" .

Answer (score 7):

> what are these "statement positions".

Places in the code where it is valid to put a *statement*.

Syntactic constructs are divided into groups, one of them being *statements*. The other big group is *expressions*. In general you can think about the difference between those as that *expressions* generate *values*, whereas *statements* describe what to do purely as "side effects".

For example, the structure of an `if` statement is

```
if (<expression>) <statement>
```

The condition of an `if` statement needs to be an *expression* and the body needs to be a *statement*. A *statement* can **never** be put in the place of an *expression* since it doesn't produce a value.

For example, the addition operator is defined as

```
<expression> + <expression>
```

Since an `if` statement is *not* an expression, you cannot do

```
42 + if(...) {}
```

---

To learn more about which statements and expressions are available, you can look at the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/), but it's not necessarily an easy read. [YDKJS - Grammar](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/93abe1810e84253ed46535120a3c62a8e309edda/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md) might be a bit easier to understand.

---

> I read that function declarations can appear only in statement position.

It's actually a bit more complicated than that. *Function declarations* are not statements, they are *declarations*. Officially declarations are only valid at the top level of the global scope and in function declarations. However, most environments allow function declarations in other places, unfortunately evaluating these cases in different ways.

Because of this, ECMAScript 6 added compatibility rules to explain this behavior, but it's not something that should be relied upon. See also [Why is a function declaration within a condition block hoisted to function scope in Chrome but not Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25111087/218196) .

When the article says *"A function declaration is a statement."*, then that's certainly a simplification.