# JavaScript scope for var and function when declared in same if block

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, scope, var

I was trying to learn about javascript scope. I read a few articles and found out that let and const have block scope.

so something like this is as expected:

codeblock 1:

```js
function letScopeTest() {
  let a = 'a';
  console.log('in letScopeTest scope', a);

  if(true){
    let a = 'b';
    console.log('in if scope', a);
  }

  console.log('in letScopeTest scope', a);
}

letScopeTest();
```

Also, I read that var and function declaration get hoisted in javascript and they don't have block scope like `let` and `const`.

So, I wrote this snippet which is also at some point understandable:

codeblock 2:

```js
function checkShape() {
  var shape = 'square';
  console.log(`'shape' variable got declared in checkShape Scope`,shape);
  var shape = 'rectangle';
  console.log(`'shape' variable got reassigned value 'rectangle' in checkShape Scope`,shape);
  if(true){
    console.log(`'shape' function declaration got hoisted in checkShape Scope`,shape);
    function shape() {};
    console.log(`'shape' function declaration found in checkShape Scope`,shape);
    shape = 'triangle';
    console.log(`'shape' function declaration got reassignment in if Scope`,shape);
  }
  console.log(`'shape' function found in checkShape Scope`,shape);
}

checkShape();
```

But things get interesting when swap `shape = 'triangle';` with `function shape() {};`

Something like this:

codeblock 3:

```js
function checkShape() {
  var shape = 'square';
  console.log('1',shape);
  var shape = 'rectangle';
  console.log('2',shape);
  if(true){
    console.log('3',shape);
    shape = 'triangle';
    console.log('4',shape);
    function shape() {};
    console.log('5',shape);
  }
  console.log('6',shape);
}

checkShape()
```

If I remove if statement then the result is still understandable:

codeblock 4:

```js
function checkShape() {
  var shape = 'square';
  console.log(`1`,shape);
  var shape = 'rectangle';
  console.log(`2`,shape);
  // if(true){
    console.log(`3`,shape);
    shape = 'triangle';
    console.log(`4`,shape);
    function shape() {};
    console.log(`5`,shape);
  // }
  console.log(`6`,shape);
}

checkShape();
```

because variable assignment gets precedence over function declaration as shown in **codeblock 4**.

But why **codeblock 2** and **codeblock 3** is not yielding the same result? I am bit new to javascript. can anyone please help me understand what exactly is happening in **codeblock 2 vs codeblock 3** or point me to some resource to understand the behavior?

I went through this links which is duplicate of the current question:

[Function declaration in block moving temporary value outside of block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619924/function-declaration-in-block-moving-temporary-value-outside-of-block)

[What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

[How does this hoisting work with block scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66756997/how-does-this-hoisting-work-with-block-scope)

So, as per me in codeblock 2 ***shape*** variable should be reassigned value 'triangle' in checkShape scope and it should print tringle in last console.log same as codeblock 3. But instead why it is printing function body?

Comment: Functions *are* block scoped post ES6 and follow weird rules for web compatibility. In reality, you should ***never*** write any code like that. Literally the only time I encounter this is questions on SO where people do weird stuff  that is there only to be confusing. I've never actually seen real code that has to rely on the web compat semantics.

Comment: agreed @VLAZ, I should not write this kind of code. But I just want to understand what exactly is happening in codeblock 2 vs codeblock 3. can you point me to any resource where can I find the rules?

Comment: See the linked duplicates. It's called the web compatibility (web compat) semantics.

Comment: @VLAZ, I go through the linked duplicates, and as per me codeblock 2 and codeblock 3 both should print the same output as codeblock 3. why it's printing function body instead of 'triangle' in the last console.log statement?

Comment: @VLAZ, I went through the links that you mentioned. Nowhere it is explained why swapping the lines is changing the output of codeblock 2 vs codeblock 3