# The output result is 1, what is the reason for this

Tags: javascript

I wonder why the output is '1'.

```js
var a
{
  a = 1
  function a() {}
  a = 3
}
console.log(a) // 1
```

Comment: You should not declare functions in a code block, behavior of the code becomes unpredictable. If you remove the function declaration, you'll get `3` as you probably have expected. I'd recall I've seen a warning about this unpredictable behavior at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), but it's not there anymore.

Comment: While obviously this would be a terrible structure to use in real code, it does make for an interesting question.

Comment: Actually the warning is there: ["_In non-strict code, function declarations inside blocks behave strangely. Do not use them._"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#block_scoping_rules_with_var_or_function_declaration_in_non-strict_mode), just not with red background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this hoisting work with block scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66756997/how-does-this-hoisting-work-with-block-scope)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function declaration in block moving temporary value outside of block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619924/function-declaration-in-block-moving-temporary-value-outside-of-block)

Answer (score 12):

This is not something that you should do in your code. Will try to break down what is happening.

Pre-requisites

- [What is the scope of variables in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Adding some identifiers to the code

```js
// statement1
var a

{
  // statement2
  a = 1

  // statement3
  function a() {}

  // statement4
  a = 3

  // statement5
  console.log(a)
}

// statement6
console.log(a)
```

**Explanation**

Initial variables table

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

###### Execute `statement1`

It will declare a variable `a` in global scope

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | global | undefined |

###### Execute `statement2`

It will assign `1` to the global variable `a`

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | global | 1 |

###### Execute `statement3`

It declares a function named `a` in the block scope

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | global | 1 |
| a | block | function |

###### Execute `statement4`

It is assigning value `3` to `a` and it will pick the nearest defined `a` to assign the value to. In this case, it will assign `3` to the block scoped `a`

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | global | 1 |
| a | block | 3 |

###### Execute `statement5`

It will log the nearest `a`, in this case the block scoped `a`'s value is `3`.

> After the block completes, it will pop the `a` from the variables table and now the table will look like this:

| variable | scope | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | global | 1 |

###### Execute `statement6`

It will log the nearest `a`, and in this case, it is the global var, and the value is still 1