# Is there a reason why angular.js developers prefer function named function expressions for controller and link functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this is close to duplicating

[Are named functions or anonymous functions preferred in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript)

or the even more popular

[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

(to name a few) questions, but after reading neither really satisfactorily answers my question.  I think I understand the difference between function expressions, named function expressions, and function declarations (well, almost understand...).

When I create directives, my usual style is something like this:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
       ...
       controller: function($scope){
       }
   };
});
```

Looking at a lot of the angular.js source, it seems they prefer

```
angular.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
       ...
       controller: function myDirectiveCtrl($scope){
       }
   };
});
```

I would think this might be useful if you are going to use myDirectiveCtrl inside of itself, but this isn't the case for most angular directives.

Is this just a style choice or is there an advantage or reason for using named function expressions when declaring controllers, link functions, etc.?

Comment: Named functions are easier to debug, stack trace will show something useful instead of "anonymous function" call.