# var NAME = function NAME (){ }; - Function Name used twice

Tags: javascript, function

In Javascript, one standard way to declare a function is as follows:

```
var add = function(a,b){
   return a+b;
};
```

However, when I repeat the function name on the right side of the syntax, I get no errors either.

```
var add = function add(a,b){
  return a+b;
};
```

What's going on in the second case?

Comment: More related info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/4962525) explains your question very well. Dumbed down, the latter is a named function (which could be helpful e.g. in a stack trace where you would see the name of the function instead of `anonymous function`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two uses of the `function` keyword in Javascript: function *declarations* and function *expressions*. Function *declarations* don't allow anything to the left of the keyword, *e.g.*

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

and they *always* require a name, *e.g.* `add`. Meanwhile, your examples invoke the other type, function *expressions*, which *don't* require a name (but *can* be named!) and  *always* require something to their left, *e.g.* your

```
var add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
};
```

or even a single parenthesis:

```
(function(a,b){
    return a+b;
})(1,2); // 3
```

So now that we've got some vocabulary down, what you've got in your second example, reprinted—

```
var add = function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
};
```

—is a function *expression* (namely, variable assignment into `add`) whose function happens to be *named*.

Now, what's the purpose of this *named* function expression?

It's expressly for accessing the function *within* itself! According to [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function),

> If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression. **This name is then local only to the function body (scope).**

Let's rename your `add`s so we can talk about things less confusingly:

```
var abc = function xyz(a,b){
    return a+b;
};
```

In the above, `abc` will be accessible in the outer scope, while `xyz` will *not* be. Meanwhile, vice versa: `abc` will *not* be accessible in the inner scope, while `xyz` *will* be.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and concise.

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
var add = function add(a,b){
  return a+b;
};
```

Could be interpreted roughly as

```
// the scope of outer `add` is here
var add = function (a, b) {
   var add = ...self... // something like that. the scope of this `add` is here

   return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases you are ended up having a function called `add()`.

But the following behavior is interesting against this backdrop.

```
var add = 1;
function add() {};

add();     //<-- Error not a function
```