# When to use function expression and when to use function declaration

Tags: javascript

Here i have two questions regarding javascript functions

1. When to use function declaration and when to use function expression
2. **This is an function expression**

   var run = function (){
    // code stuff
    }

**This is an function declaration**

```
function walk(){
// code stuff
}
```

**What do we call functions written inside below object(human) is it declaration or expression?**

```
var human = {

  think : function(){

       }

 roll : function(){

     }

 }
```

Comment: `human.think()` and `human.roll()` is a function expression

Comment: The functions inside object are called `methods`

Comment: @gurvinder372 haha.. I too thought about the same. But he is asking the technical term to pronounce that.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-or-anonymous-functions-preferred-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am not sure about a technical term that is specified for this particular scenario but `Behaviour` or `Method` (as Tushar mentioned) could be the term used for this (since this is specified inside a class/function).