# React element type is invalid - ES6 destructuring syntax error when passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm building a React app and attempting to update some JavaScript functions to use ES6 destructured arrow syntax.

Index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function TestMe() {
  const name = "User";
  const message = "Welcome!";
  return (
    <div>
      <Hello name={name} />
      <Message message={message} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestMe/>, document.querySelector('#root'));

const Hello = ({ name }) => (
    <span>Hello, {name}</span>
);

function Message(props) {
  return (
    <div className="message">
      {props.message}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Message function will render, but the Hello function throws the following error in the browser (after successful build):

"""
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `TestMe`.  """

Here's my package.json, just in case:

```
{
  "name": "jsx-exercises",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What happens if you move `const Hello` in front of the `function TestMe` ?

Comment: Look up "function declaration/function expression hoisting" and their differences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081593/are-named-functions-preferred-over-anonymous-functions-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations in Javascript get "hoisted", which means that they can be accessed in the whole scope, even before they are declared. If you use a function declaration also the initialization happens when the scope starts:

```
 { // scope begins
   a();
   function a() { }
 } // scope ends
```

Now variables can only be accessed after they were  initialized:

```
 setTimeout(() => console.log(a)); // 1
 console.log(a); // undefined
 var a = 1;
```

In your case you access `Hello` before it was initialized.

---

Fun fact: Accessing variables declared with `let` or `const` before the initialization happened throws a SyntaxError (for a good reason, [q.e.d.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)) so one can see that your building pipeline replaced `const` with `var` to support older browsers.

Comment: Great tips, too! Thank you!

Comment: @lane glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You must move `Hello` on the top of your file, because `TestMe` can't see this const. Functions javascript can see anyway, because it's function declaration

Comment: "can't see this const" ... what?

Comment: your function inside constant